# How Do I Query A Child Model Restricting Results Based on Parent Model in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm not sure how to even phrase this question... but here is a try. I'm calling the Book the "Parent" model and the Author the "Child" model.

I have two mongoose models--- Author and Books:

```
var Author = mongoose.model("Author", {
  name: String
});

var Book = mongoose.model("Book", {
  title: String,
  inPrint: Boolean,
  authors: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Author"} ]
});
```

**I am trying to run a query which would return all of the authors (child model)  who have books (parent model) which are inPrint.**

I could think of ways to do it with multiple queries, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it with one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `populate` as stated in the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

> There are no joins in MongoDB but sometimes we still want references to documents in other collections. This is where population comes in. Read more about how to include documents from other collections in your query results here.

In your case, it would look ***something*** like this:

```
Book.find().populate('authors')
.where('inPrint').equals(true)
.select('authors')
.exec(function(books) {
  // Now you should have an array of books containing authors, which can be
  // mapped to a single array.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this problem today and solved it:

```
Author.find()
    .populate({ path: 'books', match: { inPrint: true } })
    .exec(function (err, results) {
        console.log(results); // Should do the trick
    });
```

The magic occurs in the `match` option of `populate`, which refers to a property of the nested document to populate.

Also [check my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572839/mongoose-query-nested-document-returns-empty-array)

EDIT: I was confusing books for authors, now it's corrected

Comment: I don't think this will work because there is no path to books from Author-- you can get to Author from books--- but not the other way around.

Comment: I agree with @ek_ny